# Docker: Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 8 ms: Connection refused

Tags: docker, colima

I pulled a python docker image using:

```
docker pull python:3.8
```

Then I started a simple http server with:

```
docker run -ti -p 8080:8080 900972ffeecd python -m http.server 8080
```

If I `docker exec` into the container and run `curl localhost:8080` I get the response I expect, but if I run the same `curl` command from the host machine it fails.

Shouldn't using `-p 8080:8080` be enough to expose the port?

Potentially relevant info: I'm using colima on MacOS.

Comment: you may need to force the server to run on 0.0.0.0 instead of it's default which is likely to be 127.0.0.1

Comment: Running `docker run -ti 900972ffeecd python -m http.server 8080 --bind 0.0.0.0` didn't make any apparent difference.

Comment: did you also -p that time?

Comment: oh, you are on mac. errrrrr

Comment: Oh, yeah. I realized my mistake and then tried `docker run -ti -p 8080:8080 900972ffeecd python -m http.server 8080`, to no avail.

Comment: $docker inspect <docker-container-name> and then that_ip:8080 ?

Comment: maybe host.docker.internal:8080 https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/

Comment: Actual command I used: `docker run -ti -p 8080:8080 900972ffeecd python -m http.server 8080 --bind 0.0.0.0`

Comment: `curl host.docker.internal:8080` results in `Could not resolve host: host.docker.internal` and `curl`ing the IP I got from `docker inspect <container-id> | grep -i IPAddress` hangs forever.

Comment: that's me out of ideas!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to attempt, Paul. I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 2):

I hate to admit, but restarting my machine sent the issue away.

Comment: Here also. Had same issue. After restart MacBook it worked again. :disappointing: